# jQuery ui spinner - using for time (hours)

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-ui, time, spinner

Using jQuery 1.9.1 & jQuery-ui 1.10.3.  Want to use a spinner for a time (hours) control.  In addition to having a finite set of values, I want to have it roll over to 0 once it has gone beyond 23.  I have that part working.  What I am having problems with is when it starts.

The code I use for the spinner:

```
$(function() {
    $("#mystarttime").spinner({
        numberFormat: "d2",
        spin: function(event, ui) {
            if (ui.value > 23) {
                $(this).spinner("value", 0);
                return false;
                    }
            else if (ui.value < 0) {
                $(this).spinner("value", 23);
                return false;
                    }
            console.log("start spin - " + ui.value );
            }
        });
});
```

The input:

```
<label for="mystarttime">Start Time (hr):</label>
<input type="text" id="mystarttime" name="startTimeVal">
```

When the page loads, the spinner has nothing in it.  If I click the up arrow on the spinner (to increment), the `spin` event fires & I get a message in the console showing the value (1).  However, if I click the down arrow on the spinner, the `spin` event doesn't fire, but I get a 23 in the input box.  It's not until I click the down arrow again that the `spin` event fires, and the input (and console) both show 22.

If I click the down arrow once, the input box shows 23 (but no event fires).
After that, if I click the up arrow once, the input shows 00 (but no event fires).

I must be doing something wrong or looking at the wrong event to detect the roll over & change but haven't found a good example that both rolls over and sees the event.  Would appreciate any thoughts or suggestions on how to resolve this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`spin:` is not called when you set the value yourself. but `change:` is called - this should do the trick:

```
function log(value) {
 console.log(value);
}

$(function() {
    $("#mystarttime").spinner({
        numberFormat: "d2",
        spin: function(event, ui) {
            if (ui.value > 23) {
                $(this).spinner("value", 0);
                return false;
                    }
            else if (ui.value < 0) {
                $(this).spinner("value", 23);
                return false;
                    }
            log(ui.value);
        },
        change: function(event, ui) {
            log($(this).spinner("value"));
        }
        });

});
```

Comment: thank you for the reply.  I was able to put code in similar to the <0 and > 23 to make it default to one or the other if the user put in a value (-4 or 38).  However, if you put in a value like `12:45` - the change event still tries to process that.  How do you restrict it from accepting extraneous input data, or handling it once they've entered it?